# How to center JQuery Cycle slideshow hidden in the Bootstrap accordion?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-cycle

I am using Bootstrap 3 and Jquery Cycle 2 (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/) to build an accordion with a hidden slideshow at page load. Here is the HTML:

```
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-slideshow">
    <div>click to see slideshow</div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="my-slideshow">           
    <div id="slideshow" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true" data-cycle-center-horz="true" data-cycle-auto-height="container" data-cycle-slides="> div">
        <div>slide 1. blah.....</div>
        <div>slide 2. blah.....</div>
        <div>slide 3. blah.....</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is Javascript:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({});
```

This HTML works well except one thing: the slideshow is not centered within the browser. If I remove class "collapse" from #my-slideshow and load the page, then the slideshow is indeed centered on screen, but this is not what I need.

I am working on a mobile website, and the screen size is the reason why I need to hide the slideshow at page load (use "collapse" class). Any fix?

Thanks and regards.

**UPDATE**

Here is the fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/FDH2K/10/  (thanks to isherwood's orginial code!). You can see the effect by adding and removing "collpase" class.

Comment: Here's a starter fiddle. See if you can demo the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/FDH2K/

Comment: I added another Cycle2 script needed to center the slideshow: jquery.cycle2.center.min.js. You can see the effect by adding and removing "collpase" class. I added this script but it appears not to persist. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: @isherwood, could you please add  http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.center.min.js as another resource for the demo? I tried but it does not persist for other users.

Comment: @isherwood, i created a jsfiddle account and was able to add the needed cycle 2 script. However, the fiddle URL for the demo is different. I hope you dont mind. I updated my post and gave credit to you there.

Comment: No worries. That's how fiddles work. (And it was your code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the centering happens if you resize the browser (or the panel in JSFiddle). That would seem to indicate that the centering plugin can't do its thing until the carousel is visible.

Try initializing it programmatically after the accordion panel is visible using a Bootstrap Collapse callback.